# Gremlin remove all Vertex

Tags: neo4j, gremlin, graph-databases, truncate

I know how to remove a vertex by id in Gremlin.
But now I'm need to cleanup the database.
How do I delete multiple vertices?

Deleting 1 v is like this:

```
    ver = g.v(1)
    g.removeVertex(ver)
```

I mean something like SQL `TRUNCATE`. How do you remove the vertices / vertexes without removing the class?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you can try

```
g.V.each{g.removeVertex(it)}
g.commit()
```

Answer (score 60):

In more recent terms as of Gremlin 2.3.0, removal of all vertices would be best accomplished with:

```
g.V.remove()
```

**UPDATE:** For version Gremlin 3.x you would use [drop()](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#drop-step):

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().drop().iterate()
gremlin> graph
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
```

Note that `drop()` does not automatically iterate the `Traversal` as `remove()` did so you have to explicitly call `iterate()` for the deletion to occur. Iteration in the Gremlin Console is discussed in detail in this [tutorial](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/#result-iteration).

Also, consider that different graph systems will potentially have their own methods for more quickly and efficiently removing all data in that system. For example, JanusGraph has this approach:

```
 JanusGraphFactory.drop(graph)
```

where "graph" is a `JanusGraph` instance you want cleared out.

Comment: How would you do this for large graphs? I tried this with a graph with around 200k vertices and it was painfully slow.

Comment: Faster methods exist, but may be dependent on the graph database itself (like, if you were using Titan you could probably use the `TitanCleanup` utility - http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/javadoc/0.5.0/com/thinkaurelius/titan/core/util/TitanCleanup.html).  There is no "Gremlin" way to remove all vertices faster.

Comment: For those using JanusGraph you would want the JanusGraphCleanup utility -https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/dbbda285af0b3752b75178aa4dd62516200c50d5/janusgraph-core/src/main/java/org/janusgraph/core/util/JanusGraphCleanup.java

Answer (score 35):

If you are using Tinkerpop3 (Titan 1.0.0), as said before, the command is:

```
g.V().drop()
```

### Why this did not work for me

This only works if you are using the Gremlin interactive REPL interface. Why? `drop` returns an iterator that must be traversed to be applied **and** the Gremlin REPL interface automatically iterates over returned iterators.

### How I fixed it

If (like me) you are using an HTTP or WebSocket interface to Gremlin, you must explicitly iterate over the returned iterator:

```
g.V().drop().iterate()
```

### Do not forget...

...to commit the transaction. In Titan, transactions are opened implicitly but **must be closed explicitly**:

```
g.tx().commit()
```

Comment: Thank you! This also worked for Stardog/Gremlin via Java.

Comment: wow, I spent an hour on this wondering why it doesn't work, thank you

Comment: Add me to the list of people who you've saved lots of time for :) I had no idea the REPL auto iterates. The iteration fixed it for me with Tinkerpop 3.3.1 with Neo4j as a backend.

Answer (score 8):

In TinkerPop3:

> The drop()-step (filter/sideEffect) is used to remove element and properties from the graph (i.e. remove).

```
g.V().drop()
```

Comment: This is what works on AWS Neptune. It's Incredible so many people reposted this answer and this one appears at the bottom. I traditionally look for the first replier to give my vote accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it as follows;

```
graph.shutdown();
TitanCleanup.clear(graph);
```

Comment: Although the OP asked for a gremlin answer, this works in Java by passing in a com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanGraph as 'graph' in the example above.

Answer (score 5):

Blueprints used to have a clear() method for this...

`g.clear()`

But it was recently removed:

https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/issues/248

Answer (score 3):

In TinkerPop3, with Titan-1.0.0,

```
g.V().drop()
g.tx().commit()   (commit the changes)
```

works for me. You can give a try

Answer (score 0):

```
public class JanusGraphCleanup {
    @Deprecated
    public static void clear(JanusGraph graph) throws BackendException {
        JanusGraphFactory.drop(graph);
    }
}
```

Ref: https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/master/janusgraph-core/src/main/java/org/janusgraph/core/util/JanusGraphCleanup.java