# Why does my Gremlin query not drop all the vertices I indicate?

Tags: java, groovy, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am running a Gremlin query against Neptune 1.1.1.0. For development purposes, I'm trying to remove a vertex with a specific phone number along with its related `Subscription` and `Channel` vertices. I have a `union` statement that correctly emits the desired vertices in the Gremlin console, and I can apply `elementMap()` to print out all the properties:

```
gremlin> g.V()
  .hasLabel('Identity').has('phones', '+11234567890'))
  .union(
    identity(),
    __.out('Receives').hasLabel('Subscription'), 
    __.out('MemberOf').hasLabel('Channel')
  )
==>v[d5bc0f8a-a5a5-4209-8bbf-43ea1c39a694]
==>v[d0183e2b-74a8-446c-b378-903dcfc5f50f]
==>v[aba2577f-9244-4367-bcb6-209b9fbe4548]
```

```
gremlin> g.V()
  .hasLabel('Identity').has('phones', '+11234567890'))
  .union(
    identity(),
    __.out('Receives').hasLabel('Subscription'), 
    __.out('MemberOf').hasLabel('Channel')
  ).elementMap()
==> // prints out properties for each of the 3 vertices
```

However, if I apply `drop()` to the query, the first (`Identity`) vertex is dropped, but not the subsequent ones. I expected that when I had a traversal with multiple matching vertices, all of them would be dropped (e.g., `g.V().hasLabel('Identity').has('phones', startingWith('+1')).drop()` drops all North American vertices). Why is Neptune/Gremlin stopping at the first vertex in this case?

```
gremlin> g.V()
  .hasLabel('Identity').has('phones', '+11234567890'))
  .union(
    identity(),
    __.out('Receives').hasLabel('Subscription'), 
    __.out('MemberOf').hasLabel('Channel')
  ).drop()
```

(I would generally attempt to run an `explain` here to get more information, but I don't know how to make that work with `drop()` as a final step.)

Comment: When adding the `drop()` step, where are you placing that?  At the very end of the query?

Comment: @TaylorRiggan Added a copy with the `drop()` step included.

Comment: Does it work if you add `.iterate()` to the end after `.drop()`

Comment: @tim_yates No change, and I wouldn't expect a change since `drop()` ends its traversers.

Comment: Sorry, I was going from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17250723/6509

Comment: @tim_yates That seems to be an error on Stephen's part, as the Gremlin console implicitly iterates over results (though it would in fact be necessary in business code!).

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a deeper look at this, it looks very familiar, but I'm not quite remembering the behavior here.

I can also reproduce this with just TinkerGraph and Gremlin console.

For now, as a work around, try doing `fold().unfold().drop()`

I'm pretty sure I have seen this before and there may even be a TinkerPop Jira open for it. I'll do some more research and update this answer if I find anything relevant. Hopefully for now you at least have a workaround.