# Delete All Vertex Classes on OrientDB

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop3, dml, orientdb3.0

How do you remove all Vertex Classes on an [OrientDB Server](http://orientdb.com/docs/latest/)? 
I'm cleaning up the graph-database for fresh imports with fixed and simpler names and properties. 
I'm running an [OrientDB with Gremlin Server](https://orientdb.org/download) instance since this would preferably be written in Gremlin, but SQL would work fine too.

[image: OrientDB with demodb (root) user login]

I'm running a [`OrientDB 3.2.18 GA Community Edition (April 13th, 2022)`](https://orientdb.org/download) and using [Apache TinkerPop 3](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/index.html).
I've [deleted of all the Vertexes / Vertices `g.V().drop()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35414485/11705601) and
I can see how to 1-by-1 in [SQL `DROP CLASS [class-name]`](https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/SQL-Drop-Class.html), but I'm looking to delete multiples if not all.

I've tried [internet-searching](https://dkuppitz.github.io/gremlin-cheat-sheet/101.html),
looking around on [Stack Overflow Q&As](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gremlin), and
reading the [documentation](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.6.2/dev/io/);
but I haven't come across the information.
I just don't know where to look, if the info's properly documented, or I just am not reasoning where the information should be right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit janky but can get rid of these classes by:

1. Shutdown the OrientDB-Server (Optional?)
2. Navigate to ${OrientDB-Server Directory}\databases[Database-Name]
3. Delete the Related Files

   1. `rm -rf [pattern]`

Upon OrientDB-Server restart/refresh this will remove the Vertex-Classes.

[image: After cleanse]