# Why Do Vertexes Not Drop With g.V().drop()?

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, tinkerpop3, java-17, gremlin-server

## Problem

How do you cleanup [Vertexes (and Edges)](https://dkuppitz.github.io/gremlin-cheat-sheet/101.html) with [`GraphTraversalSource g`](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/dsl/graph/GraphTraversalSource.html)?

I don't understand why [`g.V().drop()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814305/gremlin-remove-all-vertex) doesn't work with `traversal().withRemote()`
When I have this working fine with `OrientGraph.traversal()`.
How do I [`drop()`](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#drop-step) Vertexes with `GraphTraversalSource g`?

```java
GraphTraversalSource g = traversal().withRemote("conf/remote-graph.properties");
```

```java
OrientGraph orientGraph = OrientGraph.open(configuration);
GraphTraversalSource g = orientGraph.traversal();
```

## Reproduction

### Steps

1. Create-and-Startup [JanusGraph [Docker-container]](https://docs.janusgraph.org/getting-started/installation/)

   ```json
   docker run -d -p 8182:8182 janusgraph/janusgraph
   ```
2. Run [`drop()`](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/3.6.2/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/dsl/graph/GraphTraversal.html#drop--) in a Java-Project
3. Results

   1. Expect: Vertexes are dropped. `g.V().count().next()` equals 2.
   2. Actual: Vertexes are not dropped. `g.V().count().next()` increases by 2.

### Logs

I've already tried appending `.next()` onto just about everything. `g.V().drop().next()` causes

```json
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

```json
2023-05-04 08:08:03,834 [INFO] [c.j.m.Manifests.gremlin-driver-loop-1] ::    0 attributes loaded from 97 stream(s) in 20ms, 57 saved, 1788 ignored: []
2023-05-04 08:08:03,909 [INFO] [o.a.t.g.d.Connection.gremlin-driver-conn-scheduler-1] ::     Created new connection for ws://localhost:8182/gremlin
2023-05-04 08:08:03,909 [INFO] [o.a.t.g.d.Connection.gremlin-driver-conn-scheduler-2] ::     Created new connection for ws://localhost:8182/gremlin
2023-05-04 08:08:03,910 [INFO] [o.a.t.g.d.ConnectionPool.gremlin-driver-host-scheduler-1] ::     Opening connection pool on Host{address=localhost/127.0.0.1:8182, hostUri=ws://localhost:8182/gremlin} with core size of 2
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet$1.next(ResultSet.java:187)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet$1.next(ResultSet.java:169)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteTraversal$TraverserIterator.next(DriverRemoteTraversal.java:115)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteTraversal$TraverserIterator.next(DriverRemoteTraversal.java:100)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteTraversal.nextTraverser(DriverRemoteTraversal.java:92)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.remote.traversal.step.map.RemoteStep.processNextStart(RemoteStep.java:80)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.next(AbstractStep.java:135)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.next(AbstractStep.java:40)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.util.DefaultTraversal.next(DefaultTraversal.java:249)
    at Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

### Code

```
│   pom.xml
│
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   ├───java
│   │   │       Main.java
│   │   │
│   │   └───resources
│   │       │   log4j2.xml
│   │       │
│   │       ├───conf
│   │       │       remote-graph.properties
│   │       │       remote-objects.yaml
```

#### `Main.java`

```java
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversalSource;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Transaction;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Vertex;

import static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.AnonymousTraversalSource.traversal;

public class Main {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        GraphTraversalSource g = traversal().withRemote("conf/remote-graph.properties");
        Transaction tx = g.tx();
        tx.open();
        g.V().drop();
//        tx.commit();
//        tx = g.tx();
        Vertex v1 = g.addV("person").property("name","marko").next();
        Vertex v2 = g.addV("person").property("name","stephen").next();
        g.V(v1).addE("knows").to(v2).property("weight",0.75).iterate();
        tx.commit();
        logger.info("g.V().count().next():\t" + g.V().count().next());
        g.close();
    }
}
```

#### `remote-graph.properties`

```
gremlin.remote.remoteConnectionClass=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteConnection
gremlin.remote.driver.clusterFile=src/main/resources/conf/remote-objects.yaml
gremlin.remote.driver.sourceName=g
```

#### `remote-objects.yaml`

```yaml
hosts: [localhost]
port: 8182
serializer: {
  className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1,
  config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }
}
```

#### `pom.xml`

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
            <artifactId>gremlin-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>janusgraph-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.4-20230429-020227.dc3f877</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gremlin console automatically tries to `next` a traversal until an configured number of times. To have a traversal in a java program take effect, you have to add the `iterate()` yourself, so `g.V().drop().iterate()`.

Comment: I've already tried this, creates an error `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: As drop returns no results replace `next` with `iterate`